# how can I move the camera automatically around the scene?

Tags: c#, opengl

I have 5 points (x, y, z) each and I want to move the camera automatically from the first point to the second and so on but I can't imagine a way to move in the three directions at the same time. can anyone help me?

Note: by automatically I mean I'll press "s" button for example and it will move through the points

this is my camera class code so far:

```
using GlmNet;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Graphics
{
    class Camera
    {
        float mAngleX = 0;
        float mAngleY = 0;
        vec3 mDirection;
        public vec3 mPosition;
        vec3 mRight;
        vec3 mUp;
        mat4 mViewMatrix;
        mat4 mProjectionMatrix;
        public Camera()
        {

            Reset(0, 0, 1.5f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
            SetProjectionMatrix(45, 4 / 3, 0.1f, 100);
        }

        public vec3 GetCameraPosition()
        {
            return mDirection;
        }

        public mat4 GetViewMatrix()
        {
            return mViewMatrix;
        }

        public mat4 GetProjectionMatrix()
        {
            return mProjectionMatrix;
        }

        public void Reset(float eyeX, float eyeY, float eyeZ, float centerX, float centerY, float centerZ, float upX, float upY, float upZ)
        {
            vec3 eyePos = new vec3(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ);
            vec3 centerPos = new vec3(centerX, centerY, centerZ);
            vec3 upVec = new vec3(upX, upY, upZ);

            mPosition = eyePos;
            mDirection = centerPos - mPosition;
            mRight = glm.cross(mDirection, upVec);
            mUp = upVec;
            mUp = glm.normalize(mUp);
            mRight = glm.normalize(mRight);
            mDirection = glm.normalize(mDirection);

            mViewMatrix = glm.lookAt(mPosition, centerPos, mUp);
        }

        public void UpdateViewMatrix()
        {
            mDirection = new vec3((float)(-Math.Cos(mAngleY) * Math.Sin(mAngleX))
                , (float)(Math.Sin(mAngleY))
                , (float)(-Math.Cos(mAngleY) * Math.Cos(mAngleX)));
            mRight = glm.cross(mDirection, new vec3(0, 1, 0));
            mUp = glm.cross(mRight, mDirection);

            vec3 center = mPosition + mDirection;

            mViewMatrix = glm.lookAt(mPosition, center, mUp);
        }
        public void SetProjectionMatrix(float FOV, float aspectRatio, float near, float far)
        {
            mProjectionMatrix = glm.perspective(FOV, aspectRatio, near, far);
        }


        public void Yaw(float angleDegrees)
        {
            mAngleX += angleDegrees;
        }

        public void Pitch(float angleDegrees)
        {
            mAngleY += angleDegrees;
        }

        public void Walk(float dist)
        {
            mPosition += dist * mDirection;
        }
        public void Strafe(float dist)
        {
            mPosition += dist * mRight;
        }
        public void Fly(float dist)
        {
            mPosition += dist * mUp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a "code this for me" site, please provide a [mcve] and people will be more willing to help you.

Comment: I edited the question @TheChubbyPanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2D, to move from 1 point to another , you just define a 2D vector(x,y) and increase both coordinates by an amount step by step until you reach the destination. In 3D is the very same, but a Z coord is added.

What you are looking for is linear interpolation between 2 3d vectors.

I'd suggest you to create a interpolator class wich takes 2 3d points and interpolates them by a defined delta time.

Using this, you could get a point moving from point A to B, and position the camera in that position (I assume the target vector does not move).

To linear-interpolate between these points, just add A with B multiplied by delta (being delta from 0.0 to 1.0 meaning 0 is the start, and 1.0 is the end).

After the interpolation, just position the camera EYE vector on the interpolated point. After reaching 1.0 on the transition. Change the destination and origin to the next point. 
(first interpolation A->B, second B->C and such, going from delta 0.0 to 1.0).

If you need more help , just ask.

PD: seems like you need SetPosition/SetTarget methods for the camera too.